# Composer install package from private GIT repository without the .git directory

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have a project X which relies on module Y. They are both my private projects. Each have their own git repository on bitbucket. And each of them has a composer.json.

When I run `composer install` on project X, it gets Y from its repository and shoves it into X's `vendor` directory.

The problem is it also shoves a `.git` directory in `vendor/jodes/Y/`.

This is a problem because something keeps opening files in that .git directory, meaning my [continuous integration] scripts cannot then delete the `.git` directory when it repeats the process. I presume it's my IDE.

#### How can I make composer get Y from the repository, without making a `.git` directory?

X's composer.json is:

```
{
    "name": "jodes/X",
    "require": {
        "jodes/Y": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://Jodes@bitbucket.org/Jodes/Y.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems that composer basically runs `git clone` to fetch from the repository? Instead, is there a way to make it do something similar to `git archive` into the `vendor` directory? (rather than a zip file).

as a workaround I have tried configuring my IDE (Netbeans) to ignore the `.git` directory but my scripts still get the "Permission denied" error when trying to delete it.

As a bonus, I would also like to make use of other advantages of using `git archive`, such as being able to specify files or directories or other patterns which will be excluded from the archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
composer [install|update] --prefer-dist
```

should do the trick.

By default, especially when you refer to branches, instead of tags ("versions"), composer prefers to fetch the dependencies as source. If you specify `--prefer-dist` you explicitely tell composer to use the archive instead.

Comment: Thanks - just tried that after deleting the vendor directory, but same result; the `.git` directory still gets created in `vendor/jodes/Y/`. Perhaps for `--prefer-dist` to have the desired effect, I need a certain setting in one of my `composer.json` files?

Comment: @Jodes Remove the username from VCS URL: `https://bitbucket.org/Jodes/Y.git` instead of `https://Jodes@bitbucket.org/Jodes/Y.git` and it should work.